# How can I set/change the font size of UIBarButtonItem's Title

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uibarbuttonitem

Here is the example I made

```
self.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem(Title:"want to let this text be smaller", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (object sender, EventArgs e) => webView.EvaluateJavascript ("window.location.href=")), true);
```

I tried so many ways but not solve this problem yet.

Comment: Do yo want to change fontsize of all elements in the Navigation bar?

Comment: Actually, I only want to change fontsize of someone screen's rightbarbutton, is this possible? Or change fontsize of all elements in the rightBarButton..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
var button = new UIBarButtonItem("want to let this text be smaller", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (object sender, EventArgs e) => webView.EvaluateJavascript ("window.location.href="));

var fontAttribute = new UITextAttributes();
fontAttribute.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(8);

button.SetTitleTextAttributes(fontAttribute, UIControlState.Normal);

NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(button, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But I **can't get the value** of `button.GetTitleTextAttributes(UIControlState.Application)`
error told me it's NULL...

Comment: Its ok now. I tested in and is correct. IControlState must be IControlState.Normal.